# Python TextBlob Package - Determines POS tag for '%' symbol but do not print it as a word

Tags: python, textblob

I was banging my head with the python's TextBlob package that

- identifies sentences from paragraphs
- identifies words from sentences
- determines POS(Part of Speech) tags for those words, etc...

Everything was going well until I found out a possible issue, if I am not wrong. It is explained below with sample code snippet.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
sample = '''This is greater than that by 5%.''' #Sample Sentence
blob = TextBlob(sample)                         #Passing it to TextBlob package.
Words = blob.words                              #Splitting the Sentence into words.
Tags = blob.tags                                #Determining POS tag for each words in the sentence

print(Tags)
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('greater', 'JJR'), ('than', 'IN'), ('that', 'DT'), ('by', 'IN'), ('5', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')]

print(Words)
['This', 'is', 'greater', 'than', 'that', 'by', '5']
```

As seen above, blob.tags function is treating '%' symbol as a separate word and determines POS tag as well.

Whereas blob.words function is not even printing '%' symbol either alone or together with its previous word.

I am creating a data frame with the output of both the functions. So it is not getting created due to length mismatch issue.

Here are my questions. 
**Is this possible issue in TextBlob package by any chance ? 
And is there any way to identify '%' in the Words list ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping off punctuation at tokenization seems to be a conscious decision by the TextBlob devs: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py#L624

They rely on NLTK's tokenizators, which take an include_punct parameter, but I don't see a way to pass include_punct=True through TextBlob down to NLTK tokenizer.

When faced with a similar issue I've replaced interesting punctuation with a non-dictionary text constant that aims to represent it, ie: replace '%' with 'PUNCTPERCENT' before tokenizing. This way, the information that there was a percent symbol doesn't get lost.

EDIT: I stand corrected, on TextBlob initialization you can set a tokenizer, through the `tokenizer` argument of its `__init__` method https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py#L328.

So you could easily pass TextBlob a tokenizer that respects punctuation.

```
respectful_tokenizer = YourCustomTokenizerRepectsPunctuation()
blob = TextBlob('some text with %', tokenizer=repectful_tokenizer)
```

EDIT2:  I ran into this while looking at TextBlob's source: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py#L372 Notice the docstring of the words method, it says you should access the tokens property instead of the words property if you want to include punctuation.

Comment: so TextBlob does not identify any symbols as separate words ? But same TextBlob does identify the symbol belongs to 'NN' POS tag right ?

Comment: That seems to be the default behaviour, yes. But please take a look at the edit on my answer, there's a way to pass a custom tokenizer to TextBlob. You could pass a custom tokenizer that respected punctuation

Comment: What if we use NLTK tokenizer to achieve the same ?. It seems it is identifying the '%' correctly. Please see my answer itself and let me know your thoughts

Comment: That's a possibility. I ran into this while looking at TextBlob's source: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py#L372  Notice the docstring of the `words` method, it says you should access the `tokens` property instead of the `words` property if you want to include punctuation.   I suggest you try that

Comment: Yes @L.Alvarez . That's a great find. So we can use TextBlob itself instead of going to NLTK.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the tokens option. According to me this would be the best answer than my answer of using NLTK package :-)

Comment: I just updated it, and I hope that solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found out that NLTK is identifying the symbols properly. The code snippet for the same is given below for reference :

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag
Words = word_tokenize(sample)
Tags = pos_tag(Words)

print(Words)
['This', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'that', 'by', '5', '%']

print(Tags)
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('better', 'JJR'), ('than', 'IN'), ('that', 'DT'), ('by', 'IN'), ('5', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN')]
```